# Using assigned variable to an InArgument<>

Tags: c#, xaml, android-activity, workflow-foundation-4

I want to use an `InArgument` parameter in my Activity. I use an `expressionTextBox` to showing and using the `InArgument` value in XAML code. My problem is this I declare a variable and assign it to this `expressiontextbox` in Activity Library designer. When in the `Execute()` method of the activity, I change the value of `InArgument` parameter - I want the variable value to change too. How can I do it?

My code is like this...

```cs
...
public InArgument<string> AcceptedForms{ get; set; }
...

protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
{
    ...
    string AForms= "#AcceptedForms_"+ this.Id;

    AcceptedForms.Set(context, AForms);
    ...
}
```

I can use the value of `AcceptedForms` in this method after changing it's value. But it doesn't pass to the variable that I assign to it in Activity Library Designer. I want to use it's value in another Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do that because when they are passed into the WF runtime **I don't think** they are passed by reference. So, what you'll have to do is setup an OutArgument that you set while in the Execute method and set that OutArgument -- in the workflow -- to the variable.

**UPDATE**

If you can take 15 minutes and watch this [video](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Endpoint/endpointtv-Workflow-and-Custom-Activities-Best-Practices-Part-3/) I think you'll better understand what's going on. And BTW, below is the entire list of videos in this series, it's an amazing foundation on these types of things.

- [Part 1](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Endpoint/endpointtv-Workflow-and-Custom-Activities-Best-Practices-Part-1/)
- [Part 2](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Endpoint/endpointtv-Workflow-and-Custom-Activities-Best-Practices-Part-2/)
- [Part 3](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Endpoint/endpointtv-Workflow-and-Custom-Activities-Best-Practices-Part-3/)
- [Part 4](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Endpoint/endpointtv-Workflow-and-Custom-Activities-Best-Practices-Part-4/)
- [Part 5](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Endpoint/endpointtv-Workflow-and-Custom-Activities-Best-Practices-Part-4/)